What is the dikduk of this word?
In Shemos 36:7, it says וְהַמְּלָאכָ֗ה הָיְתָ֥ה דַיָּ֛ם לְכׇל־הַמְּלָאכָ֖ה לַעֲשׂ֣וֹת אֹתָ֑הּ וְהוֹתֵֽר׃
I am confused as the dikduk of the last word (and I am far from a grammarian, so bear with me please…). I am looking at the website “Pealim” and the only thing I see with this conjugation is the hifil male singular imperative (https://www.pealim.com/dict/801-lehotir/). But that’s not the sense of the verse at all. All the translations translate it as descriptive (“there was left over”) as opposed to a command to leave materials over!
What is the correct understanding of the dikduk of this word?

It's 36:7. And I've only ever seen וְהוֹתֵר. Where is your version from?

Thank you, corrected it. This is copy pasted from Sefaria (“The contemporary Torah, JPS, 2006”, although I thought that was more for the English, no?)

This form is known as the infinitive absolute, which with sound verbs in hif'il takes the form הַקְטֵל. Here, we're dealing with a root whose first letter is י/ו, so we get הוֹתֵר.
Regarding meaning: the infinitive absolute is used as a noun, adverbially, replacement for a finite verb, ... Regarding ones like our case, Joüon/Muraoka write (section 123x):

The inf. abs. quite often (especially in the later books) continues a preceding form. The Waw, which usually precedes the inf. abs., sometimes has the value of a simple and, and sometimes that of and (then), indicating succession. The reasons which have motivated the choice of the inf. abs. are not clearly understood: sometimes there is probably a desire for variety or a stylistic affectation; sometimes the author wished to use a form with a vague subject like one or they. The inf. abs. virtually has the same temporal or modal value as the preceding verb.

Here, the preceding verb is היתה, a qal perfect (suffix conjugation) form, which has past tense meaning, so we attribute the same to הותר. As another example, you can see a verse with a number of infinitives absolute (bolded) in Haggai 1:6:

‮זְרַעְתֶּ֨ם הַרְבֵּ֜ה וְהָבֵ֣א מְעָ֗ט אָכ֤וֹל וְאֵין־לְשׇׂבְעָה֙ שָׁת֣וֹ וְאֵין־לְשׇׁכְרָ֔ה לָב֖וֹשׁ וְאֵין־לְחֹ֣ם ל֑וֹ וְהַ֨מִּשְׂתַּכֵּ֔ר מִשְׂתַּכֵּ֖ר אֶל־צְר֥וֹר נָקֽוּב׃
You have sowed much and brought in little; you eat without being satisfied; you drink without getting your fill; you clothe yourselves, but no one gets warm; and he who earns anything earns it for a leaky purse.


So, if I’m understanding you correctly—this form would take on the properties of its preceding verb, such that if the preceding words were present or future tense this word/form would take that on?

@bobbobble Essentially, yes. Future: Lev 25:14 (קנה); jussive: Est 2:3 (ונתון); present: Est 8:8 (ונחתום). The infinitive absolute has other uses, but this is a common one.

It's basically a hiphil. The form is like הַשְׁמֵר either imperative or command or infinitive absolute, in this case the root  is יתר which in hiphil becomes a ו it's probably a infinitive absolute like a semi noun the context probably means and there was enough/leftover/too much
